# aurelia property observation for an object that is bound from the parent

Tags: aurelia

I have a question regarding aurelia. Let's say I have a product class, and this product has tags. A concrete example: A shirt is a product, and it has some tags users can query on such as Men, XL, blue etc. Their JSON representation is like

```
{
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Shirt",
  "sku": "WCZR-1",
  "tags": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "XL"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Blue"
    }
  ]
}
```

If an administrator is looking at the detail view of this product and can edit tags, s\he will be looking at a view as follows:

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label>SKU</label>
                <input type="text" value.bind="item.sku">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Tags</label>
        <tag-manager item.bind="item"></tag-manager>
</div>
```

Notice that I have another custom element called `<tag-manager>`, which is a child element of the product detail element. As you may have guessed, it exposes a bindable object in its export: `@bindable item = null;`

This way, the parent element passes in the product to the child element, where the administrator can add\remove tags by using this tag-manager. For the administrator to be able to edit tags, s\he needs to click the **edit** button.
This puts the item in the **Edit Mode**. The parent element (the product details element), does that by adding a `InEditMode` property to the product when the user clicks the **edit** button.

```
enterEditMode(){
    this.item.inEditMode = true;
    this.savedItem = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify( this.item ));
}
```

Note that the inEditMode property does not come from the web api, it is dynamically added.

Now, this mostly works, when the product is in the edit mode, the child element (tag-manager) can add\remove tags from the product, and both parent and child see that product tag collection is modified. Sample code from tag manager:

```
removeTag(tag){
    this.item.tags = this.item.tags.filter(function(el){
        return el.id !==tag.id;
    })
}

addTag(tag){
    this.item.tags.push(tag);
}
```

these functions work and modify the item's tag collection successfully, one thing that is not working is the **product.InEditMode** property. When the parent element (the detail view puts the product in the edit mode, the tag-manager recognizes this only for the view activation. But clicking edit | cancel at the parent after initial load and changing the inEditMode property in the parent is not reflected in the child view afterwards. So although the tag property of the product is being observed, the inEditMode property is not being observed by the child. If I import the observer locator in aurelia and watch the property, it does not make a difference. Sample code:

```
import {ObserverLocator} from 'aurelia-framework';

    var subscription = this.observerLocator
      .getObserver(this.product, 'inEditMode')
      .subscribe(this.onChange);
  }
      onChange(newValue, oldValue) {
      //this method is called only once at the activation of the child,
      //no clicks in the parent can trigger this method again
      }
```

As seen in the comments, the `onChange` method is called only once on activation; after activation, no clicks on the parent (edit, cancel edit) will be reflected in the child element and onChange won't be called again.

I was able to get this working by using `eventAggregator` but I really would like to know why I cannot observe a bool property of an object from the parent.I don't want to abuse `eventAggregator` without understanding what's going on behind the scenes. Any clues will be appreciated!

**Edit**:

The plunker for this problem is at

http://plnkr.co/edit/0gMZFhtKA2r6nec9kGUC?p=preview.

Slightly different issue than what I am seeing but the child view still does not reflect changes at the parent viewmodel.

Comment: sorry, I did not understand what you are asking. Could you summarize your question into just a few words?

Comment: If you have two custom elements, where element1 is the parent of element2, both elements have access to the same instance of a data object, (because it is bound to both elements by the bindable decorator), how can you observe the changes on a property of this data object without using event aggregator?

Comment: Your code as you described it should work fine. I added something like that in my app and it works. You have some inconsistencies in naming (item/product, InEditMode/inEditMode) - is it just in the question or also in your code? Where do you call subscribe - in bind() function? Anyway, I suggest you to make a runnable plunkr to illustrate your problem.

Comment: Naming inconsistencies are just in the question, I will work on creating a plnkr. Thanks for the comment btw

Comment: Plnkr added. http://plnkr.co/edit/0gMZFhtKA2r6nec9kGUC?p=preview

Comment: Your plnkr is not set up correctly - could this also be the problem in your actual code?  

In the 3 places where babel-options are defined, if you are going to use decorators, you need this:  
  babelOptions: {
    "optional": [
      "runtime",
      "es7.decorators",
      "es7.classProperties"
    ]
  },
3 places: config.js, karma.conf.js, babel-options.js

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a slightly different approach, using `BindingEngine`:

```
@bindable product;
productChanged(newValue, oldValue) {
  if (this.inEditModeSubscription) {
    this.inEditModeSubscription.dispose();
    this.inEditModeSubscription = null;
  }
  if (newValue) {
      this.inEditModeSubscription = this.bindingEngine
          .propertyObserver(newValue, "inEditMode")
          .subscribe(this.onEditModeChanged);
  }
}
inEditModeSubscription = null;
```

Adding the property-observer for `product.inEditMode` from within `productChanged` makes sure you don't accidentally add the observer to a `null` or `undefined` object, and it will refresh the subscription whenever your `product` is set to a different object.

This ensures that your `onEditModeChanged` is always fired when the property changes.